# Whats a solution for using Profiles in asp.net Web Applications?

Tags: asp.net, profiles

What solutions are available to access Profile information since Web Applications do not expose ProfileCommon class like Web Site projects do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst possibly not the best option (but like you didn't find an obvious other option - it doesn't help that I'm also using a custom profile object), I've used the following:

```
ProfileBase pb = ProfileBase.Create(Page.User.Identity.Name);
m_PreferredName = pb.GetPropertyValue("WebName") as string;
```

More details, including examples of getting it into a custom type can be found in the [Create Method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151825.aspx)